# LQR Infinite Horizon vs. Finite Horizon vs. Receding Horizon?

Tags: pid-controller, linear-regulator

I don't know if this is the right forum, but I would like to know in words the difference between these 3 forms.
I have searched online and in books but there are often demonstrations packed with formulae, I would like a more verbal explanation that is more practical .. pretend to explain it to someone who knows nothing about control theory and this field.
Examples of real practical cases are welcome.

If you want to attach links that explain it well, go ahead!

Comment: is [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator) verbal enough for you?

Comment: I also have those formulas in the book, but I would like to know real practical cases where one result is preferred for rather than another

Comment: @KaleM Would you consider just word descriptions? Or do you require "real practical cases" to be included in an answer. It looks like you are asking for the former in the question, but now the latter in your comment. If the comment is more the case, perhaps you should re-edit your question to include that new requirement? Also, if you require practical examples in each case, such that the reasons for choosing each over the other is concretely made, that greatly lengthens any answer. Just be aware of what you ask for. You missed asking about the "receding horizon control with a finite horizon."

Comment: Thanks! Just edited

Comment: @KaleM I'm open to making an attempt at a short set of descriptions. Keep in mind my own ignorance as you read, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to put it in words and without math. I'm also no expert on the topic. I've read a few things. That's all. So take none of this as gospel. It's just my modest attempt to help a little taken from what little I've read.

- ***Infinite Horizon***: In this case the theoretical objective is to optimize the control actions over *an infinite time horizon*. Here, the controller seeks to minimize the infinite sum of future costs. The control input at any time is determined by considering the *entire future trajectory of the system*. In practice, the horizon is still finite but at least several times the dominant time constant of the system (or the slowest oscillation period.) If, for example, that period is 10 seconds then perhaps 100 seconds or more would be considered 'infinite' for practical purposes. And, of course, experience may make adjustments to the exact meaning. It probably should be taken to just mean "long."
- ***Finite Horizon***: In this case the theoretical objective is to optimize the control actions over *a finite time horizon*. Here, the controller seeks to minimize the cost-sum over some finite interval. The control input at any time is determined by considering the future trajectory of the system *only up to the end of the finite time horizon*. Of course, this means "shorter" and is generally meant to reduce the otherwise more difficult and/or complex computational requirements of the 'infinite horizon' case. It should be long enough to capture transients but short enough to be tractable, whatever that may mean.
- ***Receding Horizon***: In this case, aka model predictive control (MPC), the control input is still being optimized over a finite time horizon, but now the finite horizon is being shifted forward at every time step. Unlike the *finite horizon* case, the controller re-solves the solution at each time step. The choice here is made if the computational requirements for the 'finite' case are small enough that they can be repeated every time step (or every two, etc.) In short, they can afford to do the computation more often, so they do. And call it something different.

In the *finite horizon* case, the solution is computed once and then applied for that finite period. There's then a question of what to do once that period has been exhausted. One answer is to deactivate the controller and just let the system continue to evolve based only upon its own dynamics. Another answer is given the name of *receding horizon control with a finite horizon*, which does the obvious thing of re-evaluating the solution at the end and setting up a new finite horizon for control. This is somewhat different from the *receding horizon* case where a new solution is computed at each time step.

The above concepts, as I think I've gathered them, also can be combined with feed-forward control strategies. For example, if some of the system's frequency characteristics (Fourier domain) are known by first analyzing impulse-responses, then the Fourier domain of the desired output can be divided by the system's frequency characteristics to get the input control to use. Since such a description of the system response function is static (and because division like this introduces more noise), this idea by itself would not be able to capture dynamic changes in the system response. But by combining this kind of feed-forward knowledge, together with the above methods (for example, the receding horizon control) a more robust and adaptable control solution may be had.

I guess it is very hard to capture a definition here, as there are very smart people applying themselves to increasingly difficult control problems. So it's very hard to put all that into nice, neat boxes. I believe the reality is actually quite complicated, in practice. So, I believe the above is more about how something may be taught in class in pretty boxes that are easily handled than about observing existing practice and finding natural demarcations in meaning.

If I had to pick something to hang a hat on, it would be more about the number of taus (using the shortest oscillation period of interest: \$\tau\$) used. Approaching or exceeding \$10\tau\$? It's likely 'infinite horizon.' Below that, it starts looking more like 'finite horizon.' If the calcs are repeated frequently but cover a period enough less than \$10\tau\$, then it's 'receding horizon.'

That's my take. Had someone more knowledgeable been here to do better than the above, I'd have more than gladly let them do so. The only reason I'm adding this is because no one has given it a try, yet. Hopefully, my writing (and mistakes?) will motivate someone more experienced into writing. If so, I'll delete my writing here. (And keep in mind that the above comes only from what I've read. While I've done designed closed loop controls with success in the past, none of it was in this category.)